# NodeJS only using 10% of allocated memory

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, amazon-ecs, amazon-eks

I am noticing that all of my NodeJS applications (running on AWS ECS or AWS EKS) are only using 10% of the memory allocated to them, no matter how high or low I put the max memory at. Has anyone dealt with this before / is there something I am missing that could be causing this?

This is what is set

```
export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=1536"
exec node --max-semi-space-size=64 -r ./build/server/preload.js ./node_modules/.bin/next start --keepAliveTimeout 61000
```

Example:

Max Memory on pod: 6GB
NodeJS memory used: 600mb

So, I set the max down to 2GB, and the results are below:

Max Memory on pod: 2GB
NodeJS memory used: 200mb

I would expect to see 600mb still, not a pattern of "only use 10% of the available memory". I have tried playing around with --max-old-space-size with no luck.

Comment: Have you monitored your application's memory usage during periods of high activity?

Comment: If you want kubernetes to reserve the max memory for the pod/container, you should to set the container's requests and limits to your desired maximum. how are you measuring memory in use?